# Why .map on a mutableList doesn't actually change values inside of List in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

This is what I have and what I want to achieve:

1. I have a class which has a `mutableList` as a field.
2. I want to find a specific element inside that list and change it.

This is what I've tried so far:

1. This is the functional statement I was hoping would have worked, after I've also put it in an Extension function:

   ```
   fun Classroom.setNewParameters(id: String, modifiedName: String) {
       this.students.filter { l -> l.id == id }
                    .map { l -> l.name = modifiedName }
                    .toList()
   }
   ```

   But the list `students` appears to be unchanged after this function is called.
2. I found an "ugly" solution with the code below:

   ```
   fun Classroom.setNewParameters(id: String, modifiedName: String) {
       for (l : Student in this.students) {
           if (l.id == id) {
               l.name = modifiedName
               break
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Still tho, I'd really like to know why the first block of code behaves like it does and doesn't actually have any effect on the list.

Comment: I can't reproduce (but you're seriously abusing map(): there's no reason to create a new list just to mutate one of the elements of the original list). https://gist.github.com/jnizet/a25b87ff33ca156f446adbc8d6548bac. Post a complete minimal program reproducing your issue.

Comment: @JBNizet yeah you're right that was totally not cool. I don't know why I got stuck with the .map (the real case is a little more complex but still doesn't make sense to use .map). I guy posted a good answer below but he deleted it, anyway he just told me to go with `students.forEach({ if (it.id == id) it.name = modifiedName })` and that seems to work just fine! Do you think it's a good solution as well?

Comment: No. I think you should rather use `list.find { it.id == id }?.name = modifiedName`. That's what matches your second snippet: find the *first* element with the given id, and change its name.

Comment: @JBNizet how can I apply your solution if I need to update more than one value? i.e. I need to edit the name and surname at the same time? I can't think of anything else than repeating the find operation multiple times (which is bad I guess)

Comment: `list.find { it.id == id }?.apply { name = modifiedName; surName = modifiedSurname }`

Comment: @JBNizet right, apply. Totally forgot about that (still a damn noob). Thanks a lot, this was all really helpful, I think you should post an answer so that I can mark it as solved!! Thanks a lot again, really.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of `map` as a way to transform input to get new output. Normally it should not mutate state inside, in other words it should be a function without side effects to pursue maintainability

In your case you clearly want to mutate elements, for that you might want to use that code snippet:

```
fun Classroom.setNewParameters(id: String, modifiedName: String) {
    this.students.filter { l -> l.id == id }
                 .onEach { l -> l.name = modifiedName }
}
```

Also, even you used `map` incorrectly it should *must* modify field `l.name` (unless you have implemented you own delegates or getter/setter). Try to debug set breakpoint on `this.students.filter { l -> l.id == id }` and see if there are any items left after filtering